# Xilinx Spartan 6 speed sabotage?

Tags: spartan-6

I'm trying to use Spartan 6 fpgas at the speeds they purport to support in their datasheets.

However, when I try to make a bit file, I get a message saying my design is "not supported".  It compiles fully, you can run post-route simulation and other tools, but I just can't make a bit file.

If you could do what I want to do, you could run memory 4 times faster than their MIG.  I've been told, maybe they don't like that and want you to use a more expensive chip.

Does anyone know if Xilinx deliberately disables some possibilities?

I'm not saying that's bad practice. Might be good practice.

But I'd like to know if there's a way around it.  Maybe a secret switch option to "allow_unsupported"?

Comment: This isn't  specific enough you'll need to supply an example file or code of what you intend to do. I'm pretty sure the xlinxs engineers know what constraints to set in the synthesisizer

Answer (score 1):

In terms of device timing parameters, devices are individually tested and binned into speed grades based on measured performance.  The timing data that the manufacturer includes with the software and provides in the documentation is what they guarantee that every chip will meet.  However, it is certainly possible for chips to perform better than this, in fact it is pretty much guaranteed if the voltage and temperature are not at the extreme ends of the range, but the point is you won't be able to rely on this performance under all operating conditions.  Can you run things four times faster than what the documentation would imply?  Not likely.  But the tools should still let you load the design on the part, you'll just get warnings about timing violations and what not.  Just like you can over clock a desktop CPU, you can also over clock an FPGA. But the same caveats apply: YMMV.

It sounds like you either have a configuration mismatch in your ISE project, or you are trying to generate a bit file for a part you don't have a license for.  I think the toolchain would have failed before bit file generation in that case, though, so we'll need to see the actual error messages in order to help you properly.

Edit: from other posts of yours, it looks like you're running in to a DRC violation. I do not know why this is a DRC violation, but there are several possibilities. One is that the physical design of the chip does not allow this particular configuration. Perhaps the routing elements on the FPGA simply cannot be configured appropriately. It's also possible that it was designed to be configured this way, but something was wrong in the chip design and it doesn't actually work correctly (silicon errata, it happens all the time). So they don't let you use it because it doesn't work at all or doesn't work reliably. It's also possible that it was simply never supported in the software as the designers didn't think anyone would actually want to use it that way, or they didn't test that path during device manufacture and hence can't guarantee that it will work. You mentioned somewhere that the path delay for this is strangely zero, so this points to this particular feature being at least partially supported in the software, but for whatever reason the actual DRC rule that prevents use of this path takes place very late.

Comment: You're right. I just checked and WebISE does not let you select a device that it does not support, unless there's another way to set it by typing it into the text files.